# How to redirect to another port when using history.push?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a login/register app that is using a port 3000 and to_do_list app that using a port 3001. Login/register app is writting in react and to_do_list in node.js.

I would like to make a redirection to localhost:3001/todolist from localhost:3000/login  (when I log in I would like to redirect a users to another page that using other port).

My login.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { login } from './UserFunctions'
class Login extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const user = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    }

    login(user).then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.props.history.push(`/todolist`)
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                        >
                            Sign in
          </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}}export default Login
```

How to redirect users to localhost:3001/todolist from localhost:3000/login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is part of what defines the origin, so you can't change it with `history.push`. if you want to change that, you actually do have to load a new page from it.

Comment: so Can you write a proper solution to resolve this problem in react? What type of command should I use?

Comment: wouldn't `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001/yoururl'` work?

Comment: @RohitKashyap That's loading a new page, as I said you'd have to do.

Comment: I am not opposing your answer, i was aksing the op if he had tried that previously.